# Get data from CustomAdapter, to Java class

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

I have a ListView, with a TextView and a Button. I want to sent data from my CustomAdapter to the .class, but i dont know how. That is my CustomAdapter. I can get a Log or a toast with the data i want, but i dont know how to send without using an intent. Thanks ! :)

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.  ->>   return list.get(pos).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listapagos, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    final TextView listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPersona);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button BtnPago = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pago);

    final String textbutton = listItemText.getText().toString();


    BtnPago.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.e("BUTTON PRESSED: ",textbutton); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });



    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: `myCustomAdapter.getItem(index)`

Comment: But that will return the index of where i have pushed the button? I need to add something to the button listener? Thanks mate.

Comment: @Uat I can't understand the phrase "i dont know how to send without using an intent", you can use static variables, but an intent is a better choice, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Intents are mainly used to navigate between activities, and sed data between them, no? The thing is that i want to transfer the string textbutton, wich have the text of the textview near the button,to the class where i am calling the CustomAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample of using interface as a callback,

```
public static interface OnClickCallBack {
    public void onClickItem(int index);
}

public class A implements OnClickCallBack {
    MyCustomAdapter myAdapter;
    {
        myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter (list, context, this); //set this as the callback for myAdapter
    }
    @Override
    public void onClickItem(int index){
        String text = myAdapter.getItem(index);
    }
}

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private OnClickCallBack callback;
    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context, OnClickCallBack  cb) {
        callback = cb;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ....

        BtnPago.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            callback.onClickItem(position); //invoke callback
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: In that case, getItem returns a Int, no?  There is any posibility to transfer  the string textbutton to the class where i am calling the CustomAdapter? As i said, textbutton contains the text of the textview wich is close to him.

Comment: it returns `String`, did u see `return list.get(pos);` in `getItem` ?

Comment: please note, it's `getItem`, not `getItemId`.

Comment: String index="";    
        String test1= adapter.getItem(index);   

        Log.e("Button value",test1);   It says something that getItem(int) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Sorry, but  I can't understand what's your problem. And `index` surely is an integer, why using String ?

Comment: And now i set index as integer, and it says that is an object.. The only thing i want is to transfer the String textbutton, in the onClick, to the class where i am calling the CustomAdapter, and i dont know how.

Comment: pls cast object to String, `String test1= (String) adapter.getItem(index);`

Comment: Right now returns only to the Class the text of the button, in the position where i initialize the index.. And when i press the buttons it does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, but firstly please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Sure. I have some textviews, and some buttons in the ListView. I want to insert the value of the textview in a database, just pressing the button related to that textview. (TEXTVIEW----------------BUTTON).  To to that, i want to send the value of the textview, to the class where i am calling the Adapter. Thanks for helping me, and if that is not clear, please, tell me. :)

Comment: you may try using callback method. i updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but, the first 2 methods need to go in my class and the another one is a modification of my Adapter?

Comment: Did you see `class A` holds `myAdapter` ?  `A` is the class you name it. you may learn more about JAVA `interface` .

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return pos;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.  ->>   return list.get(pos).getId();
}

class ViewHolder{

    TextView listItemText;
    Button BtnPago;

    ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPersona);
        BtnPago = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pago);
    }
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listapagos, parent,false);          
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }


    holder.listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

    holder.BtnPago.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view=(View) v.getParent();
            TextView info=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtPersona)

            Intent i=new Intent(context,YourClassName.class);
            i.putExtra("info",info.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return row;
}
}
```

```
 public class YourClassName extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

            String data=getIntent().getStringExtra("info");
            Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

**And don't forget to add activity into AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourClassName"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I have just tryed that, but when i press some button, i get the toast with the value of the field of the list, but all the list disappear. It's maybe because of the intent? Thanks!

Comment: Yes!...when you click on item from list...it's mean you have selected that item...so that info is passing to new activity and displaying by Toast msg.

Answer (score 0):

I just have solved it. Just by copying the adapter right under my class, because is the only class that use the adapter. So, right now i have the data in my class and i can do all operations in the database as i want. Thanks to anyone who have tryed to help me.